# Arabic text display issues

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, android-volley

Volley response is not showing the Arabic character ف
Instead of this character I'm getting a diamond question mark � .
All the other characters are showing properly, I don't know the what is happening with this character alone.Is it the problem of volley web service?
Any help appreciated.

```
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
    String url = Config.url + "validateID";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new   Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            response = response.trim();
            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    response = new String(response.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                    response = Html.fromHtml(response).toString();
                    response = fixEncodingUnicode(response);
                    System.out.println("@@@@@@utf@@@@" + response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String respCode = jsonObject.getString("responseCode");
                        String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                        if (respCode.equals("200") && status.equals("ACTIVE")) {
                            ed_full_name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            ed_full_name_arabic.setText(jsonObject.getString("namearabic"));
                        }
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


public static String fixEncodingUnicode(String response) {
    String str = "";
    try {
        str = new String(response.getBytes("windows-1254"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String decodedStr = Html.fromHtml(str).toString();
    return decodedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Joop Eggen said, no need of html and Windows-1254 encoding. Just use the default enocding of Volley that is ISO-8859-1.

`response = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`

complete code is below.

```
final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
String url = Config.url + "validateID";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new   Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        response = response.trim();
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                response = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String respCode = jsonObject.getString("responseCode");
                    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    if (respCode.equals("200") && status.equals("ACTIVE")) {
                        ed_full_name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                  ed_full_name_arabic.setText(jsonObject.getString("namearabic"));
                    }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the patching code from a wrong encoding to a correct encoding cannot guarantee all characters survive the process. The main principle in java is that String always holds Unicode text; so there always is a conversion to bytes representing text in some encoding.

- `response = new String(response.getBytes(), "UTF-8");`

  This is wrong. `getBytes()` without charset uses the default charset from the platform which runs the current application. So it has a different effect on your development Windows PC and the production Linux server. Any effect is totally misleading.
- `response = Html.fromHtml(response).toString();`

  This encodes HTML entities. In a *request* a sign then the `<form>` is missing an `accept-encoding="UTF-8"`. Part of the request headers. Then the browser sends non-Latin as HTML entities.
  Here it might be a communication failure between layers, where the request part is missing a UTF-8 accepting header.
- `response = fixEncodingUnicode(response);` or `str = new String(response.getBytes("windows-1254"), "UTF-8");`

  Unneeded as *String in java already is in Unicode*. It would introduce a diamond whenever a Unicode symbol was not translatable in Windows-1254.

So all seems wrong. **The error seems to be made earlier on.**
Correct the requests, as otherwise a *correct* request might give wrong results. Go for UTF-8 rather than Windows-1254.

You can dump, log the bytes if the input parameter `response`, with something like:

```
Arrays.toString(response.codePoints().toArray())
```

(A hexadecimal format would be more readable.)

Comment: `response = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");` This will fix the problem. As @Joop Eggen said, no need of Windows-1254. Thanks @Joop Eggen for your valuable answer

Comment: @Jithu as long as you are aware you received UTF-8 data, translated with the default HTTP encoding probably,ISO-8859-1, You circumvented the real bug with this patch. But glad that the problem is disarmed.